# SSTABLE_SIZE_IN_MB sets up 2048 why SSTable still rolled to 12G

Tags: cassandra

table：

```
CREATE TABLE ts_kv_cf (
    entity_type text,
    entity_id timeuuid,
    key text,
    partition bigint,
    ts bigint,
    bool_v boolean,
    dbl_v double,
    json_v text,
    long_v bigint,
    str_v text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((entity_type, entity_id, key, partition), ts)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (ts ASC)
    AND additional_write_policy = '99p'
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND cdc = false
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4','sstable_size_in_mb': 2048}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '16', 'class': 'LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND extensions = {}
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 60
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128 
    AND read_repair = 'BLOCKING'
    AND speculative_retry = '99p';
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzMDB.png)

28 sstable synthesis only becomes L1
logs:

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:3] 2023-12-19 04:33:00,956 BigTableWriter.java:258 - Writing large partition msaiotsensingplatform/ts_kv_cf:DEVICE:6d73cf00-8e53-11ee-af17-332295359987:image:1701388800000 (4.441GiB) to sstable /data/cassandra/data/msaiotsensingplatform/ts_kv_cf-34a4a8208e5311eebe3f5b77f76fb8f3/nb-29-big-Data.db
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:3] 2023-12-19 04:33:06,614 CompactionTask.java:249 - Compacted (task id: 880b7730-9e27-11ee-8a63-1b9ea6be4de4, compaction history id: b49c7650-9e27-11ee-8a63-1b9ea6be4de4) 3 sstables to [/data/cassandra/data/msaiotsensingplatform/ts_kv_cf-34a4a8208e5311eebe3f5b77f76fb8f3/nb-29-big,] to level=1.  4.457GiB to 4.457GiB (~100% of original) in 74,768ms.  Read Throughput = 61.042MiB/s, Write Throughput = 61.042MiB/s, Row Throughput = ~107/s.  3 total partitions merged to 1.  Partition merge counts were {3:1, }
```

how should I do?In order to limit the size of SSTable?

Answer (score 1):

In LCS, while level 0 acts like STCS and can allow a partition to span multiple files in the level, Level 1 onwards obeys the rule that a partition will only appear in 1 file at each level as a maximum. If your partition is sufficiently large, e.g. larger than the 2 GB you set, then the file can be larger than the 2 GB.

You have a 4.4 GB partition, so the file is written to include the whole of the partition.

Re-modelling the table to have smaller partitions would be advisable.